# How to restrict access to web page by user

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to prevent the access to the entire page, the page is on the cloud becuase it is on development, im working with SEO on the page and start appearing on google.

The page is not prepared to all people and i need to restrict the access by a simple user / pass floating form.

I see one example in the past but dont remember how exactly what i must do.

I remember that in htaccess i must write some line asking for the user / pass, and that lines link to a file on server that have the data. Can be something like that?

And can i do this on a Wordprees installation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to use for .htaccess and .htpasswd files.

[Generates the necessary files for you to place on your server](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/)

There is a FAQ there as well.

Comment: He tolds about be carefull where to put the .htpasswd. The .htpasswd file can be at the same level with the .htaccess. Im very confused about where to put it. Thanks.

Comment: You place the .htaccess file in the folder you want to protect. In that file you tell it where to find the .htpasswd file on this line "AuthUserFile /path/to/passwords". You should place the .htpasswd file somewhere that isn`t in your "web" folders (like public_html or www). Go up a level or two. That way nobody can open it in a web-browser.

Comment: A more thorough explanation of htaccess and htpasswd can be found here  : http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/        Good luck!

Comment: I don't use 1&1 servers so I can't answer that question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[Create a Apache password](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking) file e.g. `/path/to/passwords`

Put this code in your .htaccess:

```
## password secure only sub.domain.com
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^sub\.domain\.com$ SECURED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Satisfy         any
Order           allow,deny
Allow from      all
Deny from       env=SECURED
```

Comment: I want restrict the entire subdamin, not only 1 uri, im looking how to create the apache file, thanks.

Comment: Pls check the edited code now, it secures one particular subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer within a WordPress site would be:

1) Go to Settings/Privacy and set the site as Ask search engines not to index this site. This will (source: [Codex: Privacy Settings explained](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Privacy_Screen):

> - Causes <meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' /> to be
>     generated into the   section (if wp_head is used) of your
>     site's source, causing search engine spiders to ignore your site.
> - Causes hits to robots.txt to send back:  User-agent: *  Disallow: / 
>     Note: The above only works if WordPress is installed in the site root
>     and no robots.txt exists.
> - Stops pings to ping-o-matic and any other RPC ping services(...)
> - Hides the Update Services option entirely on the Administration > Settings > Writing Screen with the message "WordPress is not notifying any Update Services because of your blog's privacy settings."

You should test if this is working, using for example [Google Webmaster Tools](http://google.com/webmaster/tools)

2) Add one of those plugins: [Private Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-only/), [Registered Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registered-only/) or similar. They will prompt the login form to any visitor trying to see the site.

Then, you are ready to work online without worrying about site visibility. Just remember to undo those changes, specially step 1. It could get you mad later if you forgot that. It will undermine all of your SEO efforts.

There are also some nice plugins to set a 'Coming Soon' page and still be able to work on the theme that shows the 'coming soon' only for user that are not logged in.

Best regards!